# How to change the parent page with link in iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, href

I have an iframe that contains a page within it that includes links to other pages. The problem that I am having is that when the links are pressed I would prefer the entire page to be directed there and not to just load the new page up in the iframe.

Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php Template_parts::navigation(); ?>
<iframe src="https://website.com/thepageinside" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;"></iframe>

            </body>
</html>
```

I have seen a few things on adding target="_top" to the links within the iframe but it does not seem to be working.
My reason for using an iframe here is because it is a page that is created using a web page builder and can be updated regularly. In order to put it into our format without the css bleeding into the header/theme I used an iframe.
Thank you in advance for the help.
I'm not experience in asking questions so if I missed something or you need more info let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the landing page builder that my place is using actually inserts a javascript function that messes with reaching the parent from the iframe using target in the href (or anywhere). My solution was to edit out that function then use  
As other sources say you can use "_parent" which sets the target of the link to what is outside the iframe which in some cases may not be the top. 
One way to do it for each link: 
For lookup reference you can go to: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp
using the  like I did will set the default used for all links. 
I'm not sure how many page builders have conflicts like this but mine certainly did. Took me hours to figure out I was not doing anything wrong!